# ListBox selected value showing as null

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have a list box populated with years and set for multiple selections but when the submit button is sent the values do not carry over.  I have researched and the only answers I have found is that make sure to not rebind and have it in `!= postback` which it is
code

```
          if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            CData[] Data = new Conduit().ReadObject(Global.Identifier);
            TForm VerifyAct = lClient.GetData(1stId, 2ndid);
            ddlPers.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(PersTaxDocInfoEnum));
            ddlPers.DataBind();
            ddlCorp.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(CorpTaxDocInfoEnum));
            ddlCorp.DataBind();
            var curDate = DateTime.Now.Year;
            Int32[] myYears = new Int32[5];
            myYears[0] = curDate - 1;
            myYears[1] = curDate - 2;
            myYears[2] = curDate - 3;
            myYears[3] = curDate - 4;
            myYears[4] = curDate - 5;


            DataTable yearsPast = new DataTable();
            yearsPast.Columns.Add("years");
            //yearsPast.Rows.Add(myYears);
            foreach (Int32 item in myYears)
            {
                yearsPast.Rows.Add(item);
            }
            lbYearsDataSource = yearsPast;
            lbYearsDataTextField = yearsPast.Columns[0].ToString();
            lbYearsDataValueField = yearsPast.Columns[0].ToString();
            lbYears.DataBind();
        ddlCorp.Visible = false;
        ddlPers.Visible = false;
        lbYears.Visible = false;
        btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
        }

    }
```

actual code

```
int i = 0;

foreach (ListItem item in lbYears.Items)
{

    if (item.Selected)
    {
        fooYears[0] = item.Text;
    }
}
if (ddltype.SelectedValue=="2")
{
    taxForm = ddlPers.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
else
{
    Form = ddlCorp.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

This comes up with a null exception.  I am and probably always will be a newbie to developing but I have used Visual Studio to debug and the values dont come across and I cant figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: a Submit button click will always produce a `PostBack` can you show the fully `Page_Load` event code..? looks like you are not persisting things where you thought that you may have been... also don't show code snippets with partial and or unfinished code... please show all relevant code..

Comment: I added the entire Page Load as requested

Comment: where is the Method Signature can't tell what line of code is Page_Load.. I would seriously add breakpoints and step thru the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can populate data to a **ListBox** in multiple ways. However, creating a **Table** just to assign items to **ListBox** is a little bit weird.

You can look at the following example -

### ASPX

```
<asp:ListBox ID="YearListBox" runat="server" 
    SelectionMode="Multiple" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" 
    OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" Text="Submit" />
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
        {
            string item = (year - i).ToString();
            YearListBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(item, item));
        }
    }
}

protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IList<string> selectedValues = YearListBox.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
        .Where(x => x.Selected)
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Win I tried your code and it looks nicer admittedly but unfortunately I am still getting a null exception on the date

Comment: Could you debug and step throw line-by-line, and show me which lines throw Null Exception?